# JQuery-Tabledit only updating one column at a time (What is wrong with my code)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using a JQuery-Tabledit to update the MySQL table.

the issue I'm facing is that when I update the cell value of the first column, same row value of the second column disappeared.

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my JQuery-Tabledit code

```
$('#example1').Tabledit({
url: 'logic-edit-delete.php',
editButton: false,
deleteButton: false,
columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'id'],
    editable: [[4, 'Status', '{"": "Select","P": "Present", "PL": "Planed Leave", "UPL": "UnPlaned Leave", "WO": "Week Off", "COff": "Comp Off", "PH": "Public Holiday", "UPHD": "UnPlaned Half Day", "PHD": "Planed Half Day", "LWP": "Leave Without Pay"}'], [5, 'Leavetype', '{"": "Select","SL": "Sick Leave", "CL": "Casual Leave"}']]

},
```

And PHP code to update my SQL table

```
<?php

include('db-connect.php');

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

if ($input['action'] === 'edit') 
{   
    $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET Status ='" . $input['Status'] . "', Leavetype ='" . $input['Leavetype'] . "'" ." WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'";

    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
} 
if ($input['action'] === 'delete') 
{
    mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM attendance   WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");
} 


mysqli_close($mysqli);

echo json_encode($input);
?>
```

Screenshots for your refrence 
Images
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening due to you are trying to update both columns every time. You just need to update on condition based like below:

```
    if(isset($input['Status']) && !empty($input['Status'])) {
        $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET Status ='" . $input['Status'] . "' WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'";   
    } else if(isset($input['Leavetype']) && !empty($input['Leavetype'])) {
        $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET Leavetype ='" . $input['Leavetype'] . "' WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'";
    }
```

Comment: But the example code `$sql = "UPDATE demo_inlineedit_user SET name ='" . $input['name'] . "', email='" . $input['email'] . "'" ." WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'";` working fine without if else codition

Comment: Yes because in demo code they will be passing both values name & email. Please check.

Comment: Hi, Amit your solution worked but what if I want to use the null value.
I'm not able to input the blank value in the cell.

Comment: @yatendrasinghranawat you need to set default NULL value for the column in your database structure.